# Marking Duplicate Values based on additional cell.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, excel-2010

I am looking for a way, preferable formula based, to mark if a value(name) is present in a spreadsheet more than one time based on a difference in the order# in a different column. As there are multiple lines per order some names will have the same order# on multiple lines but I do not want to mark those only if there are multiple order#s for a person. Example below (new so might not be best formatting for site, sorry.) Thanks

```
ORDER#  LN  QTY  ITEM       LOC         NAME            DUPLICATE

OD10560 1   24  part#12     Location 1  Joe John        Marked

OD10559 1   1   part#114    Location 2  Bunny Johnson   Marked

OD10569 1   3   part#444    Location 1  Joe John        Marked

OD10567 1   3   part#777    Location 2  Archy Bunker
OD10567 2   4   part#123    Location 2  Archy Bunker

OD10562 1   24  part#458    Location 1  Kay Harrison     

OD10577 1   2   part#471    Location 2  Bunny Johnson   Marked
OD10577 2   1   part#736    Location 2  Bunny Johnson   Marked

OD10563 1   2   part#778    Location 1  Mark Riddle  

OD10579 1   2   part#3347   Location 1  Terry Clark
```

Comment: I'm confused as to when something gets marked - Can you describe the actual rule you'd like to implement a bit more? - For example, why is `OD10577` marked?

Comment: I think he means: if there are 2 (or more) lines where the name is the same but the order# is different, mark those lines.

Comment: Fabio is correct, sorry wording might not be the best. @John  OD10577 is/would be marked as Bunny Johnson also has OD010559. As opposed to OD10567 Archy Bunker is on two lines but the Order# is the same on both his lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIFS` will allow you to see how many orders a person has, not including the current one.

The formula for **MARKED** would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$11,F2,$A$2:$A$11,"<>"&A2)
```

in G2, and drag down.

This will count the lines where the person has the same name, but a different order. You can simply mark those that are greater than 0.
Note that this will show the second line as 2, as *Bunny Johnson* has 2 lines with different orders (it counts both of the other lines, as they have different order numbers, even though both of those lines have the same order). This does not alter the result in any way, just explaining why it shows 2 instead of 1 for everyone else

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working, with that formula I getting 0 for a return and only a 1 on the second 
    OD10577 2   1   part#736    Location 2  Bunny Johnson   Marked

Comment: Here's the spreadsheet on GoogleDocs, which also understands COUNTIFS:  [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXwPmpu3kSIEK0PYU0thV4n8WWzolHCmKslVl115PqA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Very helpful! By the By what does the <> demote before the value?

Comment: <> is *not equal to* - scroll down to *VBA Comparison Operators* in [this list](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Operators-And-Functions.html) to find more

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to take this one step further and take the formula to to make a # for each Name that has COUNTIFS>0. I.E. John is 1 and Bunny 2 like here[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vr9kx6q5HTg91tLKI5N8elvid4ZBGiQMEqrkz7n8Td4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It may be possible. Does the number have to be the same every time, or can it change? Also, does it have to start at 1, or can it be a (seemingly) randomly assigned number?   It may be worth opening another question for this, to give it some visibility

Comment: You may be right about [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31587302/5098919)  figured I post as related. But to your questions: does need to be sequential from 1 not random. The names on the file will change from a large list of names, and really the file usually only has about 6-11 duplicate names per file so file to file doesn't matter from spreadsheet to spreadsheet if the person has the same as long as in that file it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the =COUNTIF(range, criteria) and just see if there are more than 1 counted.
Its pretty simple if you just take all of your names as the range and criteria is your name on the line you are looking at